# How to Select from four tables in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

This is the table structure

plinks

- link
- ojectidfk
- uidfk

ojects

- ojectid
- uidfk
- ojectname

Try

- useridfk
- ojectidfk
- goryidfk

gory

- goryid
- goryname

What i want to do is select the `ojectname` from `ojects` where the `plinks projectidfk` is the same in ojects and `plinks` but select everything from try where the `ojectid` is equal to the `ojectsid` where `pinks link = 8493284 AND gory id = try goryidfk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select obj.objectnamem, try.* from objects as obj 
    inner join plinks on plinks.projectidfk = obj.ojectid
    inner join try on try.projectidfk = obj.ojectid
    inner join gory on gory.goryid = try.goryidfk 
where plinks.link = 8493284
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining all four tables and use where clause for link like:

```
SELECT o.objectName, t.*
FROM ojects o INNER JOIN plinks p ON o.ojectId = p.ojectidfk
INNER JOIN try t ON o.ojectid = t.ojectidfk
INNER JOIN gory g ON g.goryid = t.goryidfk
WHERE p.link = 8493284
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `JOIN` should do this for you. You just connect tables by constraints and then retrieve whatever you want from any of those tables.

Please notice, that if you write a **pseudo-code** it would look pretty similar to the actual code. You need to use `INNER JOINs` because you want to be sure, that there are rows that share all those relations and match your criteria on `plinks.link`.

```
SELECT o.ojectname, t.*
FROM
  ojects o
  INNER JOIN plinks p ON p.ojectidfk = o.ojectid
  INNER JOIN try t ON t.ojectidfk = o.ojectid
  INNER JOIN gory g ON g.goryid = t.goryidfk
WHERE 
  p.link = 8493284
```